# Unity3d UnknownHostException

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try the following code in order load asset from my server but I could

```
using (WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload (url, version)) {
   while (!www.isDone) {
      progress = www.progress;
     yield return null;
   }

if (www.error != null) {
   throw new Exception ("WWW download:" + www.error + url);    
   callBack (false, www);
} else {
AssetBundleRef abRef = new AssetBundleRef (url, version);
abRef.assetBundle = www.assetBundle;
dictAssetBundleRefs.Add (keyName, abRef);
callBack (true, www);
}
AssetBundleManager.Unload (url, version, false);
}
```

But If I try to change the server url it's working fine.

Please help !!!

Comment: it's working on unity editor but for android mobile is not.

Comment: The correct tag for Unity3dD is #unity3d

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your android device is turned caching off.
Check it to see:

```
if (!Caching.enabled)
    GUILayout.Label ("Caching is turned off.");
```

Comment: how can I turn it on?